# Drupal 6: How can I make specific nodes only viewable to certain users?

Tags: drupal-6, accessibility, user-controls, login-control

I need to be able to grant viewing access to specific nodes on my site to a specific user but not anonymous users, and then the rest of the site open to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways for creating it
1.The best way is create a new contnet type and give permissions for certain type or users

Or

2.By using **[Path Access](http://drupal.org/project/path_access)** module you can configure what pages are visible/not visible to each of your user roles via the 'urls' tab of the 'access control' section of the Drupal Administration